# SQL Server Change Data Capture - Capture user who made the change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, audit, change-data-capture

Concerning **[SQL Server Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994(v=sql.120).aspx)**, can you track the **User** who has made the change to the row/column data or is there anyway to extend CDC to allow this? I couldn't see anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't capture username with CDC..

You have to use Auditing to do so or if this is a one time request,you can query TLOG..

Below is the connect item requesting the same..

[CDC : options to capture more data (username, date/time, etc)](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/283707/cdc-options-to-capture-more-data-username-date-time-etc)

You also can use triggers as per this article [Playing with CDC in Katmai](https://sqlblog.org/2007/06/21/playing-with-cdc-in-katmai)  from Aaron Bertrand..

**Create table :**

```
CREATE TABLE cdc.dbo_test_CT_MoreInfo
(
startlsn BINARY(10),
seqval BINARY(10),
operation INT,
username SYSNAME NOT NULL DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME(),
eventDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (startlsn, seqval, operation)
);
GO
```

**create trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER cdc.LogMoreCDCInfo
ON cdc.dbo_test_CT
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT cdc.dbo_test_CT_MoreInfo(startlsn,seqval,operation)
      SELECT __$start_lsn, __$seqval, __$operation FROM inserted;
  END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new field where the user’s details, machine, time etc. are stored and updated after each change.

Also, there are third party tools you can use for users auditing – [SQL Audit](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_audit.aspx) & [Compliance manager](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlcompliancemanager). I’ve used both and you can’t go wrong with any of them. There are probably more tools like those out there.