# Change Data Capture how to capture username

Tags: sql-server

I have read the CDC posts that I could find on here, but am having trouble finding anything relatively recent. The downfall that I see with CDC is trying to capture WHO made the change when somebody modifies data directly. I found a blog post from Aaron Bertrand from 2009 I think that suggested using an extra trigger on the CDC table, but that trigger is always called by sa, so the system_user is lost. Has anybody on here come up with a way to do this with CDC or is this strictly a trigger solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Change Data Capture - Capture user who made the change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380745/sql-server-change-data-capture-capture-user-who-made-the-change)

Comment: No, that is one of the posts I had read  and the responses are at least 3 year old, I was hoping they had changed some things. :)